# If else that checks 2 variables, but won't ignore text

Tags: excel, vba

I am running through a `for` loop and have an `if/else` statement that checks the value of the current range and sees if it is larger or equal to 1. The problem is that the value of the current range, can also be text instead of a number.

As I have it now, it sees the text as larger or equal to 1, but how can I add an extra condition to see if it is text or a number?

```
LastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 3 To LastRow
    If Range("A" & i).Value >= 1 Then
        ws2.Range("A" & var1).Value = ws1.Range("A" & i).Value
        var1 = var1 + 1
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: It really depends on why you want to check it and what the rules are. E.g. If the cell has a number stored as text, should be considered a number?

Comment: @Gserg, the answer Chronocidal wrote is the one I needed. I only need to check if the value is actually a number - sorry if that wasn't too clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since VBA will implicitly convert a text string that contains only numbers to a number for this comparison (i.e. `2>"1"` is `True`, and `2>"3"` is `False`), what you actually want to check if the value [`IsNumeric`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isnumeric-function)

```
If Range("A" & i).Value >= 1 And IsNumeric(Range("A" & i).Value) Then
```

As GSerg points out below, this will also capture Scientific or Programmer Notations, such as "&hFF" ("&h" means Hexadecimal, and Hexadecimal `FF` converts into Decimal as `255`) or "1d2" / "1e2" (the [**d**ecimal **e**xponent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E-notation) of 1 by power 2, or `1 * 10^2` = `100`).  If this is an issue, you may want to consider [using RegEx](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/1336/Using-Regular-Expressions-in-Visual-Basic-for-Applications-and-Visual-Basic-6.html) instead.

Comment: Perfect! It also solves the issue in Salims answer, when the value starts with a number, but contains text behind it.

Comment: @CustomX Well, again, it depends on what you consider a number. E.g. `isnumeric("1d2")` => `True`, `isnumeric("&ha")` => `True`.

Comment: @Gserg, just a number, no text or letter can be in the value - so in my case the IsNumeric seems to work, as 3G modem is not detected.

Comment: @CustomX Then `IsNumeric` is not going to help you, unless you can be absolutely sure there will never be anything in your data that [it sees as a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57526476/if-else-that-checks-2-variables-but-wont-ignore-text/57526884?noredirect=1#comment101520157_57526884) but you don't.

Comment: @Gserg, in what way? I added the `IsNumeric` part to the equation and it works now - all text is ignored (even if it contains numbers - like 3G modem).

Comment: @GSerg But, `&ha` *is* a number: the `&h` signifies that it's in Hexadecimal, and Hexadecimal `a` converted to Decimal is `10`.  Similarly, `xdy` is a synonym for `xey`, or `x * 10^y`, so `1d2` is `100`.  The "problem" is that `IsNumeric` recognises Scientific and Programmer Notations

Comment: @Chronocidal Yes, I know why it happens. My point is exactly that according to the OP's definition, these should not be numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Correction of your Macro

```
Option Explicit
Sub compaire_with_1()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim LastRow%, i%, var1%: var1 = 1
Set ws1 = Sheets("sheet1"): Set ws2 = Sheets("sheet2")
LastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 3 To LastRow
    If Val(ws1.Range("A" & i)) >= 1 Then
        ws2.Range("A" & var1).Value = ws1.Range("A" & i).Value
        var1 = var1 + 1
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: It would have been much clearer if you didn't add all the boilerplate code and simply advised to add `Val()` around the value.

Comment: @Salim, I agree with what Gserg added :) I ran it and it works better, but not if the value starts with a number and is followed by text (eg. 3G modem)

Answer (score 0):

May be this macro can works better

```
    Option Explicit
Sub compaire_with_Digit()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim LastRow%, i%, var1%: var1 = 1
Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1"): Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
LastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
ws2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.ClearContents
For i = 3 To LastRow
   If ws1.Range("A" & i) Like "[1-9]*" Then
        ws2.Range("A" & var1).Value = _
        ws1.Range("A" & i).Value
        var1 = var1 + 1
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```